# Link is not working in the header

Tags: html, css

When I try to link on top of banner is not working. I thing It's something wrong with Div z-index. But I couldn't get it. Can any one please help me to fix this . I have attached related with this. Please use the Following Link  to see the site.

```
http://10.8.12.41/srilanka/


     #header{


    color: #CFCFCF;
    font-weight: 600;
    /*border-bottom: 4px solid #84AE03;*/
    background:#fff;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;

      }
    #banner{
             height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 1;}
    #topnavbar{
        height: 26px;
   /* margin:-5px 102px 0 0;*/

    position: relative;
   background:url(../images/top_lin.png) repeat-x;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    float:right;

    }
    #topnavmenu{
        float:right;
        width:300px;
        padding:3px;
    }
    #topnavmenu a{
         color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed',sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    /*line-height: 35px;*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    z-index:10px;
    }
#apDiv2 {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 1;
    background:url(../images/menubg.png) repeat;
    background-color:#00247d;

}

Html
------------------------------------------------

<div id="topnavbar">
<div id="topnavmenu">
<a href="#">CheckmyTrip</a> |<a href="#">Baggage</a> | <a href="#">Travel Tips</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="banner">

<img src="images/Banner.png" />

</div>




<div id="apDiv2">
<!-- Start css3menu.com BODY section id=2 -->
<ul id="css3menu2" class="topmenu">


    <li class="toplast"><a href="contactus.php" style="height:32px;line-height:32px;"><img src="index_files/css3menu2/contact.png" alt=""/>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<p style="display:none"><a href="http://css3menu.com/">Pure CSS Dropdown Menus Css3Menu.com</a></p>
<!-- End css3menu.com BODY section -->

<p style="display:none"><a href="http://css3menu.com/">Pure CSS Dropdown Menus Css3Menu.com</a></p>
<!-- End css3menu.com BODY section -->


</div>
```

Comment: `z-index:10px` is wrong anyway

Comment: can you share your html code too ... ???

Comment: what link? can you show the relevant <a> tag in the html

Comment: Sorry, if you want us to use that link: `http://10.8.12.41/srilanka/`, then you must reconstruct the internet technology first. That is a non-routeable (internal) IP address.

Comment: http://10.8.12.41/srilanka/ is this the link its not working..

Comment: I Have attached Html code as well , Please Check it.....

Comment: Hate to be a rep hound but i'm addicted. an upvote would be nice too. Glad I could help, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` on `#banner` was most of your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/JwPjA/3/

```
 #header {
     color: #CFCFCF;
     font-weight: 600;
     /*border-bottom: 4px solid #84AE03;*/
     background:#fff;
     width: 100%;
 }
 #banner {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px auto 0;
     position: relative;
     width: 1000px;
     z-index: -1;
 }
 #topnavbar {
     height: 26px;
     /* margin:-5px 102px 0 0;*/
     position: relative;
     background:url(http://placehold.it/26x26) repeat-x;
     width:100%;
     float:right;
 }
 #topnavmenu {
     float:right;
     width:300px;
     padding:3px;
 }
 #topnavmenu a {
     color: #FFFFFF;
     display: inline-block;
     font-family:'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
     font-size: 11px;
     font-weight: 600;
     /*line-height: 35px;*/
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: auto;
     z-index:10px;
 }
 #apDiv2 {
     height: 100%;
     margin:0px auto;
     position: relative;
     width: 1000px;
     z-index: 1;
     background:url(http://placehold.it/300x300) repeat;
     background-color:#00247d;
 }
```

On a different note, I see that you are learning because this code has many things wrong with it. You are doing well but here are a few pointers. First, `float: left` and `float:right` in the same class does not make sense. Then you are also floating elements that don't need it in a few places. `position` is an advanced property that affects `z-index` in that `z-index` will not work without `position` and it can and usually should be used with at least one of these: `top` `left` `right` `bottom`. I would only use it if you think you need it. I think your layout as is can all be done without `position`.

A lot of people on the site here do not like [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/) but they are great for a beginner like you.

Keep up the good work and you will get better.